# Bug in Firebase CLI v11.2.0 - error cleaning up build images

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I just updated the Firebase CLI to the new 11.2.0 version.

When I tried to update a cloud function via `firebase deploy --only functions:func1` the following error happens:

> Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/project-123/us-central1/gcf-artifacts

And the function is not updated.

In the official [releases page](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases), there is this new change:

> Cloud Functions deployment now stores container images on Google Cloud Artifact Registry instead of Container Registry

So I think this bug might be related to the new way firebase stores functions. What should I do to deploy cloud functions again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

Since [firebase-tools v11.2.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v11.2.1) the deployment tool automatically enables the Artifact Registry API.

---

### SOLVED

Click [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com) or follow the link shown in the terminal to **enable** the artifact registry API. Now the deployment process works properly.

Edit: If you just enabled the Artifact Registry API and the deployment still fails, try running `firebase deploy functions` to create all functions in the new environment. It failed when I tried to update a single function. After that, you shouldn't get any more errors regardless of the deployment type.

Comment: Works! I have also went and enabled the App Registry after the firebase-debug.log suggested. But have crawled into found another issue, where the build still fails.

DENIED: Artifact Registry API has not been used in project 584705552269 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=584705552269 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

But I have enabled it and is enabled..

Comment: Solved t.. Enabling registry solved half of the issue, in combination with downgrading like stated above fixed it for us... Google fix the latest bug please.. And even when I downgraded I got an error: "Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /app from this server."... Solution was to delete the functions that were previously deployed with higher firebase-cloud version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, firebase bug with Firebase CLI Version 11.2.0.
Downgrade is the best option until they solve this.

Run the following command to return to last version:

*npm install -g firebase-tools@^10.2.2*

Comment: Hi @Beto Cárdenas, I managed to solve it yesterday by enabling the artifact registry API - I recommend you to check my answer if you are having the same problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I enabled it and was still getting the same error, the downgrade was the best option today.

Comment: When it fails, try running `firebase deploy functions` to create all functions again. It worked for me (v11.2.0)